# Executing a series of command with NodeJS through SSH

Tags: node.js, ssh

I have a device and I connect to it through SSH. Usually I am using Putty to execute commands.

I want to execute a series of commands through SSH using NodeJS, instead of typing them manually using putty.

I started looking for nodejs ssh client libraries, and I tried all of them - couldn't find how to use them for my usage.

What I'm trying to do:

- Connecting to my device through SSH
- Typing "en", then enter
- My device outputs "Password:" and I type to type "demo" there then click enter again
- Now I can execute commands like "dir" or access system shell

I tried 2 options:

1. Using ssh2 library (code after a successful connection):

   ```
   var Client = require('ssh2').Client;

   var conn = new Client();
   conn.on('ready', function() {
       console.log('Client :: ready');
       conn.exec('en', function(err, stream) {
           stream.write('lab');
           stream.write('\n');
           stream.write('dir');
           stream.on('data', function(data) {
               console.log(''+data);
           });
           stream.on('close', function(data) {
               console.log('Strean closing: '+data);
           })
       });
   ```

outputs:

[image]

2. Using node-ssh

   ```
   ssh.connect({
       host: 'device-ip',
       username: 'user',
       password: 'pass'
   }).then(function (result1) {
       console.log('Connected!');
       console.log('Executing "en" with demo input');
       ssh.execCommand('en', { stdin: 'demo'}).then(function (enable) {
           console.log(enable.stderr);
           console.log(enable.stdout);
           console.log('Executing "dir"');
           ssh.execCommand('dir').then(function (result2) {
               console.log('dir worked!');
                   console.log(result2.stderr);
                   console.log(result2.stdout);
                   res.send(result2.stderr);
           });
       })
   })
   ```

Outputs:

[image]

Any idea what I'm missing here / if there is better way to do this?

Comment: `ECONNRESET` and `ECONNABORTED` are usually related to protocol issues, the ssh server is resetting or closing the connection while the client is trying to send data.  Does a plain `ssh` command to the device always work without issues? Also could you include the error messages as text instead of screen shots.

Comment: @Matt when I'm using Putty to run commands it works without issues